# Issue moving file

Tags: perl

I have the following file_name:

```
my $filepath = "$common::conf{'admin_dir'}/carts/$paygate::cart_id.csv";
```

I need to move the file to another directory, but I'm having issues, I'm using the rename function.

```
rename $filepath, "$common::conf{'admin_dir'}/carts/spent/$paygate::cart_id.csv.bak";
```

However, it isn't working, I get no errors (using strict), the file remains in the same place though and is not moved.

Could anyone suggest what the issue is?

Comment: That's an unusual path string. What platform is this? What does `$common` contain? In general, `rename` won't work unless the source and destination volumes are the same. Have you tried `copy` or `move` from [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy)?

Comment: `rename` won't report any errors, so you have to check whether it succeeded. Try `rename $filepath, "..." or die $!;`

Comment: Does the (sub)directory `.../spent/...` already exist? And you have write privileges there?

Comment: Thanks guys, it looks as if the issue is the one @ssr1012 pointed out belwow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The below is not tested]: I ASSUME that file::copy or rename works with the scalar variable's and not support with methods[::].

```
$common_conf = "$common::conf{'admin_dir'}";
$paygate_cart_id_csv = "$paygate::cart_id.csv";
$paygate_cart_id_csv_bak = "$paygate::cart_id.csv";

my $orgfilepath = "$common_conf/carts/$paygate_cart_id_csv";
my $destfilepath = "$common_conf/carts/spent/$paygate_cart_id_csv_bak";

rename $filepath, $destfilepath;
```